# How to return field type from MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, fieldtype

Simple question: How can I return the field type of a MySQL table. I know about `describe` or `show column` but I just want to return that single parameter. e.g.:

```
SELECT fieldtype(mycol) FROM mytable
# should return INT or integer for example
```

Comment: If someone is trying to get types of a `query` like the title ask, that may not be simple. But creating a view for your query gives you back the good old `DESC table` ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use

```
SHOW FIELDS
FROM tableName where Field ='nameOfField'
```

This will return you result in format of

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra
```

Comment: This does not return just the field type. Is there a way to just SELECT the `Type` column from the result set? The solution doesn't seem obvious to me (nothing with SQL seems obvious to me).

Answer (score 18):

You can get this from the information_schema database:

```
select data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'myschema'
and table_name = 'mytable' 
and column_name = 'mycol'
```

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm a little late to the party. You may want to use COLUMN_TYPE rather than DATA_TYPE. It gives more info (such as precision) about the type.

```
SELECT COLUMN_TYPE
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'parts'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'price'
```

...yields...

```
decimal(11,2)
```

Comment: And:
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'xxxx'

If you have more than one database in your server.

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax also works, using describe, enter the columnName after the tableName:

```
describe tbleName columnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = Sstatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table Name");

ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
System.out.println("resultSet MetaData column Count=" + numberOfColumns);

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
 System.out.println("column number " + i);

  System.out.println(rsMetaData.getColumnTypeName(i));
}
```