# How to prevent "Data truncation: Data too long exception"

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, jersey

A user is reporting my service is returning him error, reporting following exception:

> Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'lastRegResult' at row 1
>
> Error Code: 1406

The column in question is defined as `VARCHAR(120)`, and it is quite possible the data I am attempting to store there are sometimes longer. I expected the data will be silently truncated, but it seems I was wrong.

I could shorten the data to 120 characters before calling `setLastRegResult`, but I do not want to have a hardcoded constant 120 in my code, so that I do not have to update it if the database column size will change. How can I do this cleanly?

A solution might be:

- how can I read the size of the column so that I can truncate it myself?
- or, how I can tell the JPA to perform the truncation for me?

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where quietly truncating the data is better than knowing the maximum size of the data and forbidding the user from exceeding it. Sounds like an awful user interface!

Comment: @DuncanJones The field `lastRegResult` is storing the error message for debugging purposes. It is better for me to get a part of the error message than to get none. It is not important for me to get the whole error message.

Comment: Check this it returns data of a certain field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093551/how-to-return-field-type-from-mysql-query