# How to get column type from a MYSQL database using PHP and store that in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP application that has a side menu bar with a list of links to different pages to show different tables. This application has a feature to create new side menu item and add it to the list and should be able to display its own table when clicked on it, for which i have created a table builder file common to all the side menu items, so it redirects to the same file with a default table template in it but displays the table of the menu item clicked. I have add new data and update data features to be applied to those new tables created in the application itself. So that now it displays different database tables based on the link clicked, every time there will be a new table displayed for different pages i want to write a common update statement which will change based on the table loaded. The problem is i want the type of column being loaded so that i can use switch statements to add the values to the update statement based on the type of column it is being stored like quotes('') for text etc.

I have tried using **mysqli_fetch_field_direct** function and tried to store the field type in a variable but that stores a number but not the field type.

Thank you in advance for the help. This is my first question, please don't mind with the bad structure of the question.

```
$columns= mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW COLUMNS FROM test_table"); // Selecting column titles of the table
$array = array(); // Creating the array that will contain column names
$i = 1; // Columns number
$j = 0; 
$fType = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($columns)) {
     if($row['Field'] != 'id'){
         while ($i <= sizeof($array)) {
             $name = "text";
             $var = $name . $i; // This variable is the name of the input field in the front end
             $fType[] = $columns->fetch_field_direct($i)->type; //fetch field type and store in the array
             $i++;

         }
     }
     $array[] = $row['Field']; // Saving the name of each column in an array
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093551/how-to-return-field-type-from-mysql-query

Comment: Thank you MortenSickel that helped.

Comment: "to add values ... based on the type ... like quotes"? Don't roll your own escaping system. Used a prepared statement with placeholders and let mysql do the work for you.

Comment: Can i use a prepared statement that changes with changing tables with each of different number and type of columns? I don't think that is possible Marc B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
$q = mysql_query('DESCRIBE tablename');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    echo "{$row['Field']} - {$row['Type']}\n";
}
```