# Mysql Enums selecting all columns with enum data type with specific value

Tags: mysql, enums

i'm trying to do a query to pull all columns that have an "ENUM" datatype and its value is "1" ( the enums set are 0 and 1 ), is it possible ?
i know the data type is "ENUM" , is there any keyword to specify it inside where clause ? like COLUMN_TYPE="ENUM" and this column's value =1 , FOR all selected columns

[image: screenshot of table]

my query :

```
$sql = "select * from " . $typeTable . $where;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: You want it from on specific table?

Comment: @John the enum u specified here references a column, i'm pulling * that will have a datatype enum of value 1

Comment: @Mittal yes select * from X where *'s datatype is enum and it's value is 1

Comment: Do you know column name from which we need to fetch data or you want dynamic query which will identify the column which has datatype as enum and get the valur

Comment: @Mittal Yes i want to do it dynamically, one row can contain 2 columns with enum = to 1, the other can contain 7 columns with enum = 1, i will post an image of the current data in table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return field type from MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093551/how-to-return-field-type-from-mysql-query)

Comment: @lolbas i don't want to return the data type only unless i can use where datatype= data type retrieved + value = 1, the link you provided shows queries that return a data type of single column, thanks anyway !

Comment: You can't select columns based on it's type unless you lookup in information schema database.

Comment: ok i understand, trying to find an alternative way to finish all i need in 1 query or try to break it into 2, check my current dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

To get all the enum column with their name from the table

```
SELECT Column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'myTable' and data_type = 'enum'
```

Then as you seem to use php, write another query with the result of the first.